# Why can't i insert this statement in to SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code:

```
            $uniqueSessionID = 'd41740fd9dc75cb8a3eeee27165d2323';
            $returnUrl = 'http://qapache.us.oracle.com:15671/OA_HTML/OA.jsp?OAFunc=ICX_\nCAT_PUNCHOUT_CALLBACK&OAHP=ICX_POR_HOMEPAGE_MENU&OASF=ICX_CAT_PUNCHOUT_\nCALLBACK&transactionid=1577779317'
            $timestamp = $conn->real_escape_string('2016-02-10 07:57:21');
            $cxmlVersion = $conn->real_escape_string('1.1.007');
            $payloadID = $conn->real_escape_string('20040316032452.913060910.144270@ap6172rt.us.oracle.com');

            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO return_cart_url (`sessionid`, `timestamp`, `version`, `return_url`, `payloadID`)
                        VALUES ('{$uniqueSessionID}','{$timestamp}', '{$cxmlVersion}' '$returnUrl', '{$payloadID}')";

            if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
```

And i get this error:
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

All my columns are varchar. In the beginning i only had the columns uniqueSessionID and returnURL, and with these 2 it worked. It happened when I added the timestamp, cxmlVersion and payloadID.

Anyone who can explain me why this happens?

Comment: Have tried to echoing your query and execute it inside phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forget one `,` after cxmlVersion

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO return_cart_url (`sessionid`, `timestamp`, `version`, `return_url`, `payloadID`)
                    VALUES ('{$uniqueSessionID}','{$timestamp}', '{$cxmlVersion}', '$returnUrl', '{$payloadID}')";
```

Answer (score 6):

You forgot 1 comma :

```
 '{$cxmlVersion}','$returnUrl'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it is because you are missing the brackets in the values definition of the return Url, and there is a missing colon after cxmlVersion.

```
VALUES ('{$uniqueSessionID}','{$timestamp}', '{$cxmlVersion}' '$returnUrl', '{$payloadID}')";
```

Becomes:

```
VALUES ('{$uniqueSessionID}','{$timestamp}', '{$cxmlVersion}', '{$returnUrl}', '{$payloadID}')";
```